# Elixir Atoms and its different forms

Tags: elixir

So, as a newbie to Elixir lang, I am thoroughly confused with `:` (colons) on both sides of a variable!

`:status` is an atom, but we also find in `maps` or `structs` stuff like so:

```
%{
   kkey: "success"
 }
```

Is the `kkey` an atom? If so, how is this different from `:kkey`, the standard way of declaring an atom!

Another example to drive home the point:

```
IO.inspect(some_variable, label: "value of some_variable")
```

In this example, is `label:` considered an `atom`?

Furthermore, in `Keyword List` are all keys `atoms`?

Appreciate clarifications. Thanks!

Comment: This is similar to Ruby, which can sure be confusing at first, but really natural after a while

Comment: I ACCEPTED the answer from Peaceful James as it had more information. Needless to say the answer from zwippie is also correct and equally appreciated. Thanks to Alexander too for your thoughts. I am not sure how I @users here in stack overflow!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer from zwippie is correct. I want to add one little thing. You mentioned `IO.inspect`, e.g.

```elixir
IO.inspect(some_variable, label: "value of some_variable")
```

and you are correct to assume that `label:` is an atom, but in this case it is a `Keyword` list as the second argument. The following lines are all equivalent:

```elixir
IO.inspect(some_variable, label: "value of some_variable")
IO.inspect(some_variable, [label: "value of some_variable"])
IO.inspect(some_variable, [{:label, "value of some_variable"}])
```

So a `Keyword` list in Elixir which looks like

```elixir
[a: 1, b: "yes"]
```

is actually shorthand for a "list of 2-tuples":

```elixir
[{:a, 1}, {:b, "yes"}]
```

Many times the `options` argument in a function is a Keyword list like this and if you know about the "list of 2-tuples" reality then you can use variable/dynamic keys, e.g.

```elixir
key = :label
value = "some label"
options = [{key, value}]
IO.inspect(something, options)
```

Answer (score 5):

Your assumptions are correct:

```
%{
  kkey: "success"
}
```

is equivalent to:

```
%{
 :kkey => "success"
}
```

For more information about Keyword lists, read the [documentation](https://elixir-lang.org/getting-started/keywords-and-maps.html#keyword-lists).